# Mysql: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' хотя дубля нет

Tags: mysql

Делаю запрос, получаю ошибку: Error MySQL:Duplicate entry '2022-09-16 23:15:46-bold-serv16_1-1-0' for key 'PRIMARY'
но прикол в том, что такого ключа нет ни в самой таблице, ни в самом запросе, вот запрос:

```html
INSERT INTO `control_pf_logs` (`did`,`time`,`potok`, `rid`,`lr`,`url`,`soft`,`foldername`,`inputfile`,`profile`,`status`,`message`) VALUES
(0,'2022-08-11 14:15:26',1,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:15:35',2,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:15:47',3,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:15:48',1,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:15:55',4,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:06',5,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:08',2,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:10',1,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:15',6,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:27',7,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:29',3,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',2,''),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',1,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',2,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',3,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',4,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',5,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',6,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',7,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok'),
(0,'2022-08-11 14:16:30',8,0,0,'','bold','serv16_1','serv16_2','',1,'OK: Ok')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `rid`=VALUES(`rid`),
    `lr`=VALUES(`lr`),
    `url`=VALUES(`url`),
    `foldername`=VALUES(`foldername`),
    `inputfile`=VALUES(`inputfile`),
    `profile`=VALUES(`profile`),
    `status`=VALUES(`status`),
    `message`=VALUES(`message`)
```

индексы в таблице вот такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он ругается на индекс 2022-09-16 23:15:46-bold-serv16_1-1-0
но 2022-09-16 23:15:46 это время, когда я делаю этот запрос, что за магия?

И еще немного магии, если я пошлю этот запрос удалив из запроса несколько строчек, то он выполнится, а потом снова полный запрос отправлю, и он отправится... без ошибок отправится. А спустя время, снова будут ошибки на подобных запросах.

Бьюсь над проблемой уже не первый день, такую откровенную магию в MySQL еще не видел, что я делаю не так?

Comment: там при апдейте ts обновляется, отсюда и дубли.  надо время - бери datetime. что нить из этого [If the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable is disabled, the first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: ну вот что странно, я то в запросе указываю значение `time`, а оно почему то в БД добавляется с текущем значением. Изменил на datetime колонку, поставил тестить

Comment: блин дружище, спасибо тебе, помогло заменить на datetime. Мне 3 месяца эти логи спамили и жить спокойно не давали, периодически возвращался к тестам но все тщетно было. Интересное поведение mysql, запомню

Comment: `timestamp` это не просто тип с секундами. это специальный тип данных, который может обновляться в строке самостоятельно, при изменении других столбцов строки, что видимо и происходит.